# RegEx pattern to extract authorization numbers

Tags: regex, vba

I'm using [GSKinner's Reg Exr tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?) to help come up with a pattern that can locate authorization numbers in a field that contains a whole lot of other garbage. The authorization number is a string that contains letters (sometimes), numbers (always), and hyphens (sometimes) (*i.e.* the authorization always contains a number somewhere, but doesn't always contains hyphens and letters). Additionally, the authorization number can be located anywhere in the field I am searching.

Examples of proper authorization numbers include:

```
 5555834384734  ' All digits
 12110-AANM     ' Alpha plus digits, plus hyphens
 R-455545-AB-9  ' Alpha plus digits, plus multiple hyphens
 R-45-54A-AB-9  ' Alpha plus digits, plus multiple hyphens
 W892160        ' Alpha plus digits without hypens
```

Here's some sample data with the additional garbage, which is sometimes appended to the real authorization number with a hyphen or no space, making it look like part of the number. The garbage comes though in predictable forms/words: REF, CHEST, IP, AMB, OBV, and HOLD that are not part of the authorization number.

```
 5557653700 IP
 R025257413-001
 REF 120407175
 SNK601M71016
 U0504124 AMB
 W892160
 019870270000000
 00Q926K2
 A025229563
 01615217 AMB
 12042-0148
 SNK601M71016
 12096NHP174
 12100-ACDE
 12110-AANM
 12114AD5QIP
 REF-34555
 3681869/OBV ONL
```

Here's the pattern I'm using:

```
 "\b[a-zA-Z]*[\d]+[-]*[\d]*[A-Za-z0-9]*[\b]*"
```

I'm learning RegExp so it no doubt can be improved, but it works for the above, just not for the below situations:

```
 REFA5-208-4990IP  'Extract the string 'A5-208-4990'without REF or IP
 OBV1213110379     'Extract the string '1213110379' without the OBV
 5520849900AMB     'Extract the string '5520849900' without AMB
 5520849900CHEST   'Extract the string '5520849900' without CHEST
 5520849900-IP     'Extract the string '5520849900' without -IP
 1205310691-OBV    'Extract the string without the -OBV
 R-025257413-001   'Numbers of this form should also be allowed.
 NO PCT 93660      'If string contains the word NO anywhere, it is not a match
 HOLDA5-208-4990   'If string contains the word HOLD anywhere, it is not a match
```

Can someone help?

For testing purposes, here's Sub that creates a table with sample input data:

```
 Sub CreateTestAuth()

 Dim dbs As Database
 Set dbs = CurrentDb

 With dbs
     .Execute "CREATE TABLE tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR CHAR);"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('5557653700 IP');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "(' R025257413-001');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('REF 120407175');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('SNK601M71016');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('U0504124 AMB');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('3681869/OBV ONL');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('REFA5-208-4990IP');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('5520849900AMB');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('5520849900CHEST');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('5520849900-IP');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('1205310691-OBV');"
     .Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_test_auth " _
         & "(AUTHSTR) VALUES " _
         & "('HOLDA5-208-4990');"
     .Close
 End With
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Your sample inputfile (path to this file s/b given to `function<GetMatches>` as `inputFilePath`):***

```
5557653700 IP
R025257413-001
REF 120407175
SNK601M71016
U0504124 AMB
W892160
019870270000000
00Q926K2
A025229563
01615217 AMB
12042-0148
SNK601M71016
12096NHP174
12100-ACDE
12110-AANM
12114AD5QIP
REF-34555
3681869/OBV ONL
```

***here's the junks saved in file(path to this file s/b given to `function<GetMatches>` as `replaceDBPath`):***

```
^REF
IP$
^OBV
AMB$
CHEST$
-OBV$
^.*(NO|HOLD).*$
```

***And here goes the `bas`:***

```
Option Explicit
'This example uses the following references:
'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Private fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Private re As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

Private Function GetJunkList(fpath$) As String()
0     On Error GoTo errHandler
1     If fso.FileExists(fpath) Then
2         Dim junkList() As String, mts As MatchCollection, mt As Match, pos&, tmp$
3         tmp = fso.OpenTextFile(fpath).ReadAll()
4         With re
5             .Global = True
6             .MultiLine = True
7             .Pattern = "[^\r\n]+"
8             Set mts = .Execute(tmp)
9             ReDim junkList(mts.Count - 1)
10            For Each mt In mts
11                junkList(pos) = mt.Value
12                pos = pos + 1
13            Next mt
14        End With
15        GetJunkList = junkList
16    Else
17        MsgBox "File not found at:" & vbCr & fpath
18    End If
19    Exit Function
errHandler:
     Dim Msg$
     With Err
         Msg = "Error '" & .Number & " " & _
        .Description & "' occurred in " & _
        "Function<GetJunkList> at line # " & IIf(Erl <> 0, " at line " & CStr(Erl) & ".", ".")
     End With
     MsgBox Msg, vbCritical
End Function

Public Function GetMatches(replaceDBPath$, inputFilePath$) As String()
0     On Error GoTo errHandler
1     Dim junks() As String, junkPat$, tmp$, results() As String, pos&, mts As MatchCollection, mt As Match
2     junks = GetJunkList(replaceDBPath)
3     tmp = fso.OpenTextFile(inputFilePath).ReadAll
4
5     With re
6        .Global = True
7        .MultiLine = True
8        .IgnoreCase = True
9        For pos = LBound(junks) To UBound(junks)
10           .Pattern = junkPat
11           junkPat = junks(pos)
12           'replace junk with []
13           tmp = .Replace(tmp, "")
14       Next pos
15
16       'trim lines [if all input data in one line]
17       .Pattern = "^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$"
18       tmp = .Replace(tmp, "")
19
20       'create array using provided pattern
21       pos = 0
22       .Pattern = "\b[a-z]*[\d]+\-*\d*[a-z0-9]*\b"
23       Set mts = .Execute(tmp)
24       ReDim results(mts.Count - 1)
25       For Each mt In mts
26           results(pos) = mt.Value
27           pos = pos + 1
28       Next mt
29    End With
30
31    GetMatches = results
32    Exit Function
errHandler:
     Dim Msg$
     With Err
         Msg = "Error '" & .Number & " " & _
        .Description & "' occurred in " & _
        "Function<GetMatches> at line # " & IIf(Erl <> 0, " at line " & CStr(Erl) & ".", ".")
     End With
     MsgBox Msg, vbCritical
End Function
```

***And a sample tester***

```
Public Sub tester()
    Dim samples() As String, s
    samples = GetMatches("C:\Documents and Settings\Cylian\Desktop\junks.lst", "C:\Documents and Settings\Cylian\Desktop\sample.txt")
    For Each s In samples
        MsgBox s
    Next
End Sub
```

***may be called from `immediate window`:***

```
tester
```

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, at first I thought the additional requirement would make the regex *a lot* longer.
But with positive look-ahead, it's actually almost the same size. Only the regex this time:
`\b(?=.*\d)([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)\b`

Or broken down with comments (ignore whitespace):

```
\b                     # Word start
  (?=.*\d)             # A number has to follow somewhere after this point
  (                    # Start capture group
    [a-z0-9]+          # At least one alphanum
    (?:-[a-z0-9]+)*    # Possibly more attached with hyphen
  )                    # End capture group
\b                     # Word end
```

Note however that variable-width look-ahead is not supported by all regex flavors. I don't know about the VBA one.

Second note: The `(?=)` thingy will also be satisfied if the number appears after the word end. So in
**DONT-RECOGNIZE-ME** but-1-5ay-yes
the bold part will be captured.

Comment: OT: I'm really not good with the English and the words-with-or-without-hyphen thing. Was that “Note however…” sentence correct?

Answer (score 0):

\b to start with is a problem. And also some spaces and some dashes needs to be taken care of. Try this one "`[a-zA-Z|\s|-]*[\d]+[-]*[\d]*[A-Za-z0-9]*[\b]*`" . Run this only on authorization numbers.

Comment: The `\b` at the beginning seems to be okay because the first character in the examples is always a letter or digit.  The `[\b]` at the end is incorrect (it matches a backspace character, not a word boundary), but the `*` makes it optional, so it has no effect at all.  Also, your `[a-zA-Z|\s|-]` should be simply `[a-zA-Z\s-]`; the "or" is automatic in a character class, so the `|` matches a literal `|`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two-step approach because of that additional filtering.

```
var splitter = new Regex(@"[\t\n\r]+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
const string INPUT = @"REFA5-208-4990IP
       OBV1213110379
       5520849900AMB
       5520849900CHEST
       5520849900-IP
       1205310691-OBV
       R-025257413-001
       NO PCT 93660
       HOLDA5-208-4990";
string[] lines = splitter.Split(INPUT);

var blacklist = new[] { "NO", "HOLD" };
var ignores = new[] { "REF", "IP", "CHEST", "AMB", "OBV" };

var filtered = from line in lines
         where blacklist.All(black => line.IndexOf(black) < 0)
         select ignores.Aggregate(line, (acc, remove) => acc.Replace(remove, ""));

var authorization = new Regex(@"\b([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (string s in filtered)
{
  Console.Write("'{0}' ==> ", s);
  var match = authorization.Match(s);
  if (match.Success)
  {
    Console.Write(match.Value);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

---

Prints:

```
'A5-208-4990' ==> A5-208-4990
' 1213110379' ==> 1213110379
' 5520849900' ==> 5520849900
' 5520849900' ==> 5520849900
' 5520849900-' ==> 5520849900
' 1205310691-' ==> 1205310691
' R-025257413-001' ==> R-025257413-001
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry I overlooked the *vba* tag. Nevertheless, the logic stays the same. :-)

Comment: Thanks, primfaktor! Can you help me break down the RegEx pattern you're using? After testing some data, I realize that the authorization number must at least contain one digit. Your pattern works really well, but it matches strings that are all letters, _e.g._ it matches the word "YES". How can the pattern be updated so that it must contain at least one digit?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that this was a necessity. The regex basically says „Look for at least one alphanum followed by possibly zero more alphanum strings that are attached with a hyphen.“  
Let me think of a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easy to let it go loose rather than sticking rigidly to one way or another. :)

Try this:

1 - Add this function

```
Public Function RemoveJunk(ByVal inputValue As String, ParamArray junkWords() As Variant) As String
    Dim junkWord
    For Each junkWord In junkWords
        inputValue = Replace(inputValue, junkWord, "", , , vbBinaryCompare)
    Next
    RemoveJunk = inputValue
End Function
```

2 - Now your task is easy. See the example below on how to use it:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim theText As String
    theText = " REFA5-208-4990IP blah blah "
    theText = RemoveJunk(theText, "-REF", "REF", "-IP", "IP", "-OBV", "OBV") '<-- complete this in a similar way

    Debug.Print theText

    '' -- now apply the regexp here --


End Sub
```

The completion of the RemoveJunk function call is a bit tricky. Put the longer ones before the short ones. e.g. -OBV should come before "OBV".

Give it a try and see if it solves your problem.